# How to delete rows containing Unnamed and then merge cells and keep values

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, xlsxwriter

I cannot understand how to delete the Unnamed values in one cell and unite them with the value

My Code:

```
def wrtie_xls(array):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    array.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='test1')
    writer.save()
    writer.close()

def transpon(array):
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(array)
    index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df)
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.unstack()).transpose()

array = {1: {2016: 22818888925.021294, 2017: 23215791927.55883, 2018: 24241415053.75489, 2019: 25526831987.89783, 2007: 18183059018.027966, 2008: 16868527277.51174, 2009: 18331809529.53519, 2010: 19724006864.797657, 2011: 20392912788.825798, 2012: 19580849153.840134, 2013: 22084393933.539394, 2014: 22030084567.47173, 2015: 21700822555.267574}, 2: {2016: 15081873888.10038, 2017: 15377071873.462284, 2018: 16253879799.12362, 2019: 16517025291.019705, 2007: 10038529774.615318, 2008: 11611749842.042978, 2009: 12040185617.510305, 2010: 12508816879.258118, 2011: 13711111085.100977, 2012: 13219008951.675236, 2013: 14209627046.021126, 2014: 15371996764.61913, 2015: 14417938720.997215}, 6: {2016: 0.6609381349660216, 2017: 0.6623539667069717, 2018: 0.6705004539991144, 2019: 0.6470456380505956, 2007: 0.5520814602571774, 2008: 0.6883677306864346, 2009: 0.6567919876164886, 2010: 0.6341924825418297, 2011: 0.6723468700662476, 2012: 0.6750988605150847, 2013: 0.6434239077958611, 2014: 0.6977729348945159, 2015: 0.6643959547744175}})

new_array = transpon(array)
wrtie_xls(new_array)

new_array_test = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', index_col=0)
new_array_test = new_array_test.dropna(axis=0)
rename_dct = dict.fromkeys(new_array_test.loc[:,(~new_array_test.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed',na=True))])
new_array_test = new_array_test.rename(columns=rename_dct)
print new_array_test
writer1 = pd.ExcelWriter("test_new.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
new_array_test.to_excel(writer1,sheet_name = 'Worktest',index=False)
writer1.save()
```

The result I am getting

[image: Result Error]

The result that I need

[image: Result I want]

Comment: Why can't I copy Array line?

Comment: @Johnny, I dont know